# python: Make json from multiple lists

Tags: python, json

I have the following variables in python:

**constants:**

- d["id"]

**arrays:**

- d["time"]
- d["x"]
- d["y"]
- d["z"]

Need to get a json in the following view:

```
{"data_list":[{"id":1,"time":"1","x":1,"y":1,"z":1}, {"id":1,"time":"2","x":2,"y":2,"z":2}]}
```

I've done it with iterations.
What is the quickest way?

Comment: add your try ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

d = {'id' : 1, 'time' : ['1', '2'], 'x' : ['1', '2'], 'y' : ['1', '2'], 'z' : ['1', '2']}
print(json.dumps({'data_list': [{'id' : d['id'], 'time' : t, 'x' : x, 'y' : y, 'z' : z} for t, x, y, z in zip(d['time'], d['x'], d['y'], d['z'])]}, indent=2))
```

Would give you the following JSON output:

```json
{
  "data_list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time": "1",
      "x": "1",
      "y": "1",
      "z": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "time": "2",
      "x": "2",
      "y": "2",
      "z": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import json

d = {'id' : 1, 'time' : ['1', '2'], 'x' : ['1', '2'], 'y' : ['1', '2'], 'z' : ['1', '2']}
arr = ['time', 'x', 'y', 'z']

print(json.dumps({'data_list': [dict([('id', d['id'])] + list(zip(arr, v))) for v in zip(*itemgetter(*arr)(d))]}, indent=2))
```